# Import TypeScript enum from multi-level namespace generated by TypeLITE in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, typelite

In a Angular project I use TypeLITE to auto-generate a bunch of interfaces for objects that come from the backend. That part works well and I have intellisense for objects and (to some degree) type-safety for those.

But now I came across the first class that contains an enum, which TypeLITE correctly picks up and creates the TypeScript code in enums.ts. The content of those two files look like this:

**classes.d.ts**

```
declare namespace My.Multi.Level.Namespace {
  interface MyInterface {
    Status: My.Multi.Level.Namespace.Status;
  }
}
```

**enums.ts**

```
namespace My.Multi.Level.Namespace {
  export const enum Status {
    Undefined = 0,
    New = 1,
    ...
  } 
}
```

**someOtherFile.ts**

```
// How/what to import to access this?
const status = My.Multi.Level.Namespace.New;
```

And the actual interface in "classes.d.ts" referencing that enum still works fine.

But now I try to import that namespace to access the "Status" enum at runtime and cannot figure out how to do that. The namespace is just not available, no matter what I do.

I tried changing it to "export namespace..." or even "export module ..." but that would break the code generated in "classes.d.ts". I need a solution that will allow me to use the enum at runtime as well as leaving the connection to classes intact.

I understand that there is some incompatibility when it comes to modules and namespaces, but I just assume there is some way to get around it and actually use those enums?

```
USED VERSION
Angular 4.3.6
TypeScript 2.3.4.
```

---

**EDIT:** Simplified example

If you would like to try the issue I am having on your own machine, please follow these steps:

*1)* Create a new minimal Angular app

```
ng new enumtest --minimal
```

*2)* Modify the `app.component.ts` file with this code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { My } from './classes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<p>{{myEnum}}</p>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  myEnum: My.Multi.Level.Namespace.Status;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit:begin:myEnum");
    this.myEnum = My.Multi.Level.Namespace.Status.New;
    console.log("ngOnInit:after:myEnum");
  }

}
```

*3)* Add this file `classes.ts`

```
// classes part

namespace My.Multi.Level.Namespace {
  export interface MyInterface {
    Title: string;
    Status: My.Multi.Level.Namespace.Status;
  }
}
namespace My.Other.Multi.Level.Namespace {
  export interface SomeInterface {
    Context: My.Multi.Level.Namespace.MyInterface[];
  }
}

// enums part

namespace My.Multi.Level.Namespace {
  export const enum Status {
      Undefined = 0,
      New  = 1
  } 
}

export import My = My;
```

---

Expected behaviour: "1" will be displayed on the page (value of the enum) and it still compiles as all references are still intact (like My.Other.Multi.Level.Namespace.SomeInterface.Context still connected to My.Multi.Level.Namespace.MyInterface[]).

Comment: Missing part is `export` before `namespace`. Then you can `import {My} from "..`

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried that but I think that didn't work because of the multilevel namespace? Anyway, will try that again tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Ah, now I remember. Whilst adding "export" would fix the issue that I cannot import the enum (works fine with export), it will break the link from "classes.d.ts" that use this enum (compiler says "classes.d.ts (40,53): Namespace 'My.Multi.Level.Namespace' has no exported member 'MyEnum'.")

Comment: So add `import {My} from './enums';` in _classes.d.ts_ as well

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, then _classes.d.ts_ is not working anymore as cross-referenced members are throwing errors like `[ts] Namespace '"c:/src/enums".My' has no exported member 'Subclass'.`

Comment: Too tired to write a proper answer but the solution is to `export` each `namespace` in place (`export namespace My.A`, `export namespace My.B`) and to remove the `export import = My` syntax. That doesn't work with loaders and it is probably a bug that it type checks at all. Never use that syntax in a module.

Answer (score 1):

As @Aleksey L. mentioned you need to `export` the namespace, it will work for one file, but the problem is that whenever you have an export at the top level Typescript starts to assume that the file is a module (and for a good reason).

`Namespace` at Typescript are invented in order to mimic **module** behaviour in files that suppose to be on the **global**.

You have few options:

1. If you don't need the namespace at the global, you can get rid of it, and export the enum / interface directly from each file.
2. If you do need the namespace it should be exported and all of it content suppose to be written in the same file, so the enum & the interface will be in the same file

Actually, At my work we once used namespaces heavily (when all of our code base was declared on the global), then whenever we introduced Webpack at our build system, we started to convert our code to use **ES6 modules**, one of the steps was to remove the namespaces.

We had a requirement to make that transition gradually, so some of the code used `namespaces` and some `ES6 modules`.
In order to keep the backward compatibility, we kept the files that contained the namespaces, and for each file we created a new file that reads the namespace from the global and exports it internals.

Something like that:

```
// old-file.ts
namespace someName {
   export class SomeClass {

   }
}

//old-file.es6.ts
export import SomeClass = someName.SomeClass;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that also doesn't work, maybe I am missing something here. I cannot change the namespaces as those are coming from a big project and removing or renaming them is simply not possible. I tried your suggestion with putting it into one file (so I am not using the .d declaration anymore) and the export import but the enum is still not available at runtime. Will update my question with another simplified example.